# A typical performance case of SQL Optimization

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have an engineering practice of SQL Optimization problem, which I think is a typical case ,and will help a lot of guys.

SQL SERVER 2005,

Firstly, create the main table. This is a person info table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OLAPAgentDim](
    [RoleID] [varchar](50) NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_OLAPAgentDim_RoleID]  DEFAULT ((1)),
    [OLAPKey] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FatherKey] [bigint] NULL,
    [FatherKeyValue] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [System] [varchar](6) NULL,
    [Level] [int] NULL,
    [IfLeaf] [real] NULL,
    [IfDel] [real] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_OLAPAgentDim_IfDel]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [SourceKey] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [MainDemoName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [FastCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TagValue] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Script] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Birthday] [datetime] NULL,
    [EarlyStartTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [StartTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [EndTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [EditTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [BecomesTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [ContractTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [ContractEndTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [XMLIcon] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PassKey] [varchar](50) NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_OLAPAgentDim_PassKey]  DEFAULT ('N3pkY3RHaeZXA9mGJdfm8A=='),
    [Address] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [HomeTel] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Mobile] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [IDCard] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [IDSecu] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [IDEndowment] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [IDAccumulation] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ContactPerson] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [ContactPersonTel] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Others1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SexKey] [varchar](2) NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_OLAPAgentDim_SexKey]  DEFAULT ((1)),
    [SexKeyValue] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [MarrageKey] [varchar](2) NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_OLAPAgentDim_MarrageKey]  DEFAULT ((1)),
    [MarrageKeyValue] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Nation] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Race] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PartyMemberKey] [varchar](2) NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_OLAPAgentDim_PartyMemberKey]  DEFAULT ((1)),
    [PartyMemberKeyValue] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [RegionKey] [bigint] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_OLAPAgentDim_RegionKey]  DEFAULT ((1)),
    [RegionKeyValue] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [LeaveResonKey] [bigint] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_OLAPAgentDim_LeaveResonKey]  DEFAULT ((1)),
    [LeaveResonKeyValue] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [RoleStr] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [RoleStrValue] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [LeaderKey] [bigint] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_OLAPAgentDim_LeaderKey]  DEFAULT ((1)),
    [LeaderKeyValue] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [FastCode2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [FastCode3] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [FastCode4] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [FastCode5] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [OtherAddress] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [ShowOrder] [int] NULL,
    [RaceKey] [bigint] NULL DEFAULT ((1)),
    [RaceKeyValue] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [DepartLevelKey] [bigint] NULL DEFAULT ((1)),
    [DepartLevelKeyValue] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [forumname] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [IfCloseKey] [bigint] NULL DEFAULT ((1)),
    [IfCloseKeyValue] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [InsureStartTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [AccumulationStartTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [Rate] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DirectLeaderKey] [bigint] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_OLAPAgentDim_DirectLeaderKey]  DEFAULT ((1)),
    [DirectLeaderAttriKey] [bigint] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_OLAPAgentDim_DirectLeaderAttriKey]  DEFAULT ((1)),
    [DirectLeaderKeyValue] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [DirectLeaderSourceKey] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DirectLeaderPartName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [DirectLeaderPositionName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [NOTSync] [int] NULL,
    [FatherPath] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [SaleDiscount] [real] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_OLAPAgent Dim] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [OLAPKey] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Secondly, insert abount 10,000 record into the table. I think 10,000 record is not a very big number to SQL SERVER. You can see this is a father and children dimention table in fact. The records with ifleaf=0 means the person's department structure node, the records with ifleaf=1 means the person. You can define father-children relationship using FahterKey column. For Example:

```
OLAPKey IfLeaf FatherKey DepartLevelKey  MainDemoName 
  2        0      0           1          IBM Company
  3        0      2           2          Sales Depart    
  4        0      2           2          Service Depart
  5        0      3           3          Sales Team1  
  6        1      5          NULL        John Smith
  7        1      4          NULL        Mary
......
```

DepartLevelKey Column means the depart node's level.
So in this table, we can save the whole HR tree info.

Thirdly, we see the problem SQL:

```
create table #t
(
TableID int IDENTITY(1,1),
OLAPKey bigint,
MainDemoName nvarchar(max)
)

declare @t4 table
(
TableID int IDENTITY(1,1),
MainDemoName nvarchar(max),
OLAPKeystr varchar(100)
)

declare @agentkey bigint
set @agentkey ='2'

    --Part A
    --DepartLevelKey=2, to get @agentkey node's all level=2 department

    ;WITH Result AS(
    SELECT OLAPKey,DepartLevelKey,maindemoname FROM OLAPAgentDim WHERE OLAPKey =@agentkey
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT a.OLAPKey,a.DepartLevelKey,a.maindemoname FROM  OLAPAgentDim AS a,Result AS b WHERE a.FatherKey = b.OLAPKey
    )

     insert #t select OLAPKey,maindemoname from Result where DepartLevelKey=4

    --Part B
    ;with One as  
    (  
    select *,convert(varchar(50),OLAPKey) as Re from #t  
    )
    insert @t4 select maindemoname,stuff((select ','+Re from One where One.maindemoname=#t.maindemoname for xml path('')),1,1,'') as Two  
    from #t 
    group by maindemoname  
    drop table #t
```

The SQL above is divided into Part A and Part B. 
Part A SQL get all the childrens below a root node(and filtered those belong to the specified DepartLevelKey). For example, to get all persons in Sales Department's child-department with level=3.

Part B SQL change the rows to column, For example:

```
Change:
TableID  OLAPKey MainDemoName
  1        6     Sales Team1
  2        10    Sales Team1
  3        12    Sales Team1
to:
TableID  MainDemoName OLAPKeystr
  1      Sales Team1   6,10,12
```

Thus we get each goal department's persons, for further processing(omited here).

The Problem:
The Part A is very slow, cost about 5 minutes. The Part B is slow too.

I wonder how to optimize it basing the table struc existed.

yours,
Ivan

Comment: 1) What does your SQL plan say. 2) Why are you bothering with that temp table?

Comment: You should be careful not to incur unnecessary type conversions; if you have `declare @agentkey bigint` - then ***why*** on earth are you setting that value to a **string** `set @agentkey ='2'` ????? It's a number - so just set it to a number value! `set @agentkey = 2` If you have such *implicit type conversions* in your queries, too - those are real performance killers....

Comment: Union tends to be very slow. Why don't you just left outer join?

Comment: I think this question is too big, there are too many aspects to consider. IMHO, this doesn't fit well into stackoverflow. Can't you reduce it to a minimal part?

Comment: this question is a typical case, not only single small quesions, but many aspects to consider. In fact, those aspects are not same power relation to the performance. So I think I could keep the quesiton, and test those aspects, and show what we need to pay more attention in such case.

Comment: This looks like it was a homework assignment.  Please give feedback on the one answer posted, and if it resolves your massive question, flag it as the answer.  @StefanSteinegger is right -- this should not be posted like this in StackOverflow.

Comment: From part A is obvious that the recursive will build everything - all 'nodes' and then filter out the desired node only. In my opinion no matter how you optimize this approach it will always be ineffective as table grows and tree gets more nodes and levels. A recommended approach would be to isolate the node tree objects to other tables and pass on the 'nodeid' as FK to the main table. This way you find the node(s) you want to work with and filter the rows based on a single index column on the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

**(i)** Adding this index to `OLAPAgentDim`:

```
create index IX_OLAPAgentDim_FatherKey on OLAPAgentDim (FatherKey) include (DepartLevelKey, MainDemoName)
```

**(ii)** Changing `MainDemoName` in `#t` from `nvarchar(max)` to `nvarchar(100)`. This matches the column definition in `OLAPAgentDim`.

**(iii)** Between Part A and Part B, i.e. after Part A and before Part B, adding this index to `#t`:

```
create clustered index IX on #t (MainDemoName)
```